# Can you get exact 0 or 1 fitted probabilities from logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am trying to understand logistic regression, and I have a very basic question. Given that the sigmoid function $\phi(z) = \frac{1}{1+exp(-z)}$ gives 0 or 1 only when $z=-\inf$ or $z=\inf$ respectively, I think it is impossible that we get exact 0 or 1 fitted (or predicted) probability for any combination of the finite number of real-valued input variables. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  Though real number arithmetic, and the floating point arithmetic used in all computerized computations are different, so it *is* possible to get a zero or one to within the precision that a computer can discern.

Comment: Why is this a concern to you? How regression model could possibly know that something is *sure* to happen, or absolutely impossible?

Comment: I have a related question, is there an alternative to the sigmoid function that is used that does allow 1 or 0 to be fitted?

Comment: There are alternatives but (afaik) they wouldn't have the same nice properties, e.g. they wouldn't be smoothly differentiable or monotonic. For example you could have a "double-rectified" linear function $f(x;a,b)=\operatorname{min}(1, \operatorname{max}(0, ax+b))$, but the disadvantage of that is it isn't differentiable at 0 or 1, and is susceptible to plateaus during learning since the gradient is flat when $ax+b<0$ or $ax+b>1$. Also probabilities of 1 or 0 are generally best avoided unless you're actually dealing with logical certainty or impossibility.

Comment: This occurs often with separation, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression